# How to access cookies within +layout.js in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to access cookies in the load function within `+layout.js`. I want to be able to make my header/nav in the template show "login/signup" in the nav if there is not a jwt saved in cookies, but show "logout" if there is.

Below is my `+layout.js`. I expect this to access cookies like it does in the exact same code in my `+page.server.js` file. Instead, I get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')"

```
export function load({ cookies }) {
    return {
        jwt: cookies.get("jwt")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are only available in the server events.
I.e. `+page.server.js`/`.ts` or `+layout.server.js`/`.ts`.

Universal `load` functions (without `.server`) also run on the client, which may or may not be able to access the cookies (it should not because generally cookies should be [`HttpOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#httponly)).